# Google Sheet | ArrayFormula - Get next smaller value of COL

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

Google Sheets. I want to get the next smaller value of the current value in COL A.

I've tried this...

```
=MAX( FILTER(INDIRECT("A" & ROW()-1 );MAX(A:A)) )
```

Looks good for the moment if the values in COL A are sorted.
The formula above is needed to pasted in each field.

"but", I want to use `ARRAYFORMULA()` ... I'm trying a long time (months) with breaks ...

That's one of my last tests.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ROW(G:G)=1;"Trip";  IF(ROW(G:G)<3;"0";  MAX( FILTER(INDIRECT("A" & ROW() );MAX(A:A)) )  ))
```

I've already tried VLOOKUP, too. But maybe I'm at the wrong way.

Unfortunately I didn't found a solution which match my case.

Does anybody can solve my issue? Or give me a hint to can solve this by my-self?

**UPDATE Jan 26, 2021**

Here we go... I've created a dummy sheet based on original values but cut not needed cols.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yI0UEdZ3aKU03ElPchUuAPcmnAoMmCyXWhZBcu2Hv3g/edit#gid=0

Col A - is the "current value"
Col G+H - are some tries with ArrF

Col J - is working but not with ArrF - Shows the diff to the last value. Yes this can also be done without INDIRECT() and Co. But I want to try the basic logic.

Col K - show the last value.

Currently Col A is sorted. But if not the diff isn't working. I have added some values from above (grey marked) to simulate.

The goal should be to get the next smaller value of "current" COL A using ArrayFormula.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: what do you mean by "current value" ? Do you mean top value? Would be much easier if you shared a sample sheet.

Comment: Have added an update with dummy sheet to the question it-self.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use `OFFSET`

See the docs: [`OFFSET`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379?hl=en&ref_topic=3105472)

```sh
=
{
    "Last";
    0;
    ArrayFormula( OFFSET(A3:A, -1, 0) )
}
```

```sh
=
{
    "Diff";
    0;
    ArrayFormula( A3:A100 - OFFSET(A3:A100, -1, 0) )
}
```

I changed the structure slightly so that it would be contained within arrays. That way you don't need the `IF` statements for the headers, for example.

I also did not use the whole column notation `A:A` partly because the array already has `A1` and `A2` covered. I tried `A3:A` but that didn't work for the `diff` column, because it always says it needs more rows. Probably because it needs to reference a row that is not on the same row, if that makes sense.

#### Refs

- [Arrays](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)
- [`OFFSET`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379?hl=en&ref_topic=3105472)

#### UPDATE

Due to international settings you may need to have your functions written in this way:

```sh
=
{
    "Last";
    0;
    ArrayFormula( OFFSET(A3:A; -1; 0) )
}
```

```sh
=
{
    "Diff";
    0;
    ArrayFormula( A3:A100 - OFFSET(A3:A100; -1; 0) )
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong. I've tried within cells M3, N1, O1, P3 different scenarios. All with "Error".

Btw ... For this solution A1 need to be sorted ascending. This would be solution no 2 . 

Favorit solution would be to get the highest value from A:A which is less than A(n)

Comment: Can you make your sheet public so I can see what is happening? It works for me...I just put it in the top row (L1,M1,N1...) of any column. It produces the same result as in your example sheet with the formula on each line.

Comment: Sheet already is public. :)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yI0UEdZ3aKU03ElPchUuAPcmnAoMmCyXWhZBcu2Hv3g/edit#gid=0

You suggestions in cells M3, N1, O1, P3

Comment: Its public but its view only, I can't see the formula's or edit - can you turn on editing?

Comment: I can see formula's if I you an extra browser to simulate external user.

However. I have duplicated the sheet with edit option.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15sQZJi3D7j-V9ZcoNY0wpM15tkuR4NvrRBLAFq_IyHE/edit#gid=0

Comment: Check it now, the problem was the international setting of the spreadsheet. In your country the separator between arguments in a function is `;` whereas where I am it is `,` - updated answer with that info.

Comment: @mf1   is that still not working for you?

Comment: Sorry. Didn't not tested yet. But "now" I've done ... This is working. A really good base!! Many thanks. Have added this solution to the sheet. Col R+S

Comment: But the main goal hasn't reached. Find next smaller value in Col A based on Col A (current line). Current solution works if Col A is sorted. And limited to given line numbers within formula. Yes, you already wrote about this limitation :)

Comment: Let us say Col A is sorted. This makes it easier.

I have a follow up challenge... Based on Col U shows "L" Liter, Col V should show the SUM of all diff's Col S until Col T is "y". Same for Col W with "L". Ideally Col V + Col W shows only values if Col T is set to "y".

Background: The goal should be a average calculation for fuel usage per 100km.

Comment: In the question it does not say that the solution needs to work even if unsorted. I matched your output in your sample sheet. If you have questions about how to do it sorted or your follow up challenge, you should ask another question about it. See - [How to ask follow up questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions) - I believe I answered your question as it was written above, so please accept my answer (✓), and then ask another separate question and I will have a look at it.